# How to prevent \psaxes from inheriting the grid size of the containing \pspicture?

Tags: pstricks, pst-plot

How to prevent `\psaxes` from inheriting the grid size of the containing `\pspicture`?

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=bottom](-4,-4)(4,4)
    \pnode(1,2){A}
    \rput{45}(A){\psaxes{->}(0,0)(-1,-1)(1,1)[$x$,0][$y$,90]}
    \qdisk(A){2pt}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-4,-4)(4,4)
    \psgrid[style=gridstyle](-4,-4)(4,4)
    \pnode(1,2){A}
    \rput{45}(A){\psaxes{->}(0,0)(-1,-1)(1,1)[$x$,0][$y$,90]}
    \qdisk(A){2pt}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]